# Symmetry in electrical circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, symmetry, electrical-resistance

[image]

I was able to solve the above question by assuming potentials( Nodal Analysis), but the solution was very lengthy as i had three variables and had to solve three equations.

Is it possible to solve this question using symmetry and get a quicker and more elegant solution.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The fact the battery has no resistance does not stop you from using superposition.

Comment: Yes it does. Can u elaborate ?

Comment: @Niescte Could you elaborate? Why would an ideal battery stop you from using superposition? As far as I know, it is possible and in doing so you will get a wheatstone bridge configuration on shorting one of the batteries. The elegant solution you were looking for.

Comment: FWIW, https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAnENPEPKmmEJ8qAtgDcKKXtgQopvflGU1R3ZTASdu+Hb0HCeK7UdnyDIM8clKrSpWtXL5o6Fq5GlRo1UInd3rpWvtoWShY+lqFCerQxwVEA7nHCSnKKomzJFlbplnJQWSLFnpnJtgWmBZBsAPbKhDQqkKRQsPAYhCjE2MQ0CNhgKEgw8C2dCF0j6lTYbNi8ahBgkBAASgwAzgCWmwAuAIYAdgDGDGxAA

Comment: "*the solution was very lengthy as i had three variables and had to solve three equations*" Well, objectively speaking, three linear equations is nowhere near "very lengthy".

Comment: @The Photon https://imgur.com/a/9c3hVp6 see this , superposition is not valid

Comment: @ThePhoton https://imgur.com/a/9c3hVp6 howzatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact the battery has no resistance does not stop you from using superposition.

Let's say you start by shorting the right battery and finding the currents due to the left battery.

You get 2/12 A through the resistors from A to C and C to E. And 2/8 A along the path from A to B, through the shorted battery from B to F, and then through the 4-ohm resistor from F to E. There is no current through the resistors BD or DF in this partial solution because they are shorted by the right-hand battery. And there is no current in resistor CD because of symmetry.

Now short the left battery and find the currents due to the right battery.

You get 2/6 A through resistor BD and DF, and 2/8 A through resistors AB and EF (but in the opposite direction from the current through these resistors in the first part of the solution). No current through resistors AC or CE because they're shorted by the left-hand battery. And no current through resistor CD because of symmetry.

Add these up and you get 1/6 A through resistors AC and CE, and 1/3 A through resistors BD and DF.

You get no current through resistor CD because it had no current in either of the partial solutions.

You get no current through resistors AB and EF because the currents from the two partial solutions for these resistors were equal but opposite, so they sum to 0.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9c3hVp6 How is superposition valid ???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: @Niescte, the problem in that circuit isn't that superposition requires a resistor in series with each voltage source. The problem is that it has two ideal voltage sources in parallel. Whenever you see two ideal voltage sources in parallel, alarm bells should go off, even if the two sources have the same value.

Comment: okay thanks, you cleared my concept. I think the book should have made it more clear that such a circuit with ideal voltages in parallel has not solution either through loop law or through superposition. So the problem is not that superposition cant be applied but that no solution exists for such circuits .

Comment: Do you think asking this as a question will be helpful to a broader audience ?